# Prevent custom hook from reinitialization on each re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import useInterval from "use-interval";

const useOwnHook = () => {
  const arr = [...Array(100)].map((_, index) => index);

  return {
    arr
  };
};

const Component = ({ count }) => {
  const { arr } = useOwnHook();
  console.log(arr, "arr");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count + 1}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <Component count={count} />;
}
```

I've created hook `useOwnHook` for demonstration that each time `Component` re-render, each time it goes insite `useOwnHook`, and create new array, is it possible to prevent it to move inside of this hook each time on re-render?

Comment: use a ref (or a state)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `useState` into your custom hook as:

```
const useOwnHook = () => {
  const [arr] = useState([...Array(100)].map((_, index) => index));

  return {
    arr
  };
};
```

By doing this you can keep the same array in your `useOwnHook`.

Also you can import as `import { useState } from 'react'`.

See also from the [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) documentation - *example with a different variable*:

> We declare a state variable called count, and set it to 0. React will remember its current value between re-renders, and provide the most recent one to our function. If we want to update the current count, we can call setCount.

Comment: Does it mean , that when my component was mounted, and this value was created in state , it will be memoized in memory , and it will only be recreated when unmouning happens and then it will be one more time mounter ? in other way it will be stored in memory ?

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich Extended my answer with a note from the official documentation for `useState`.

Comment: Thanks , care about perfomance in cases like this , but thanks ) it was helpful )

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use a state variable with a init function:

```js
const useOwnHook = () => {
  const [arr] = useState(() => [...Array(100)].map((_, index) => index));

  return {
    arr
  };
};
```

Benefit of the init function is that it's lazy-evaluated so you won't be constructing the array each time the component is rendered.